# How do I get category object from within an item's template?

Tags: php, k2

This is more of a PHP question but it is also related to Joomla.
In K2's `category.php` file, there are these lines:

```
    <?php foreach($this->links as $key=>$item): ?>

    <div class="itemContainer">
        <?php
            // Load category_item.php by default
            $this->item = $item;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

which iterates through items in a category and load template(`category_item.php`) for each one of them.

Now in the `category_item.php` file, I wanna get information from another item (for example, in item 2, I wanna display image of item 3, sounds weird but it is what I want to do). In `category_item.php`,this is how image gets displayed:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>">
```

the `$this` here refers to the current item, so my question is, from within the `category_item.php` file, is there anyway to refer to the category object? And is there anyway to refer to other items?

Answer (score 1):

We have `category.php` and `item.php` files.
`category.php` load template in loop like:

```
foreach($this->links as $key => $item) :
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->loadTemplate('item');
endforeach;
```

So in `item.php` file you have access or you should have to `$this` and every property you have created in `JView`.

You wanna access the next property of loop, so you need only to pass a `$key` to `item.php`

```
foreach($this->links as $key => $item) :
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->loadTemplate('item');
endforeach;
```

Then in your `item.php` you can access next value of item like so:

```
$this->links[$this->key + 1]->image
```

or other property of next, previous or what `$key` you wanna to.

Answer (score -1):

Well, although a little bit vague what you want to do, you could achieve something like this by creating an override in the **`category.php`** file and bypass the default **`item.php`** template loading, so you can easily switch back to another element of the category items array...

A very simplified example would be:

```
$i = 0;
    foreach ($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>
        <div class="item">
        <?php
        $this->item = $item;
        echo '<h2>'. $this->item->title .'</h2>';
        if ($i == 1)
        {
            $this->item = $this->leading[$i-1];
            echo '<h3>'.$this->item->title.'</h3>';
            echo '<img src="'. $this->item->imageMedium . '" />'; 
        }
        $i++;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
```

Comment: It's like a rape on a joomla ; )
You need to pass reference of `parent $category` aka `$this` to child template.

Comment: @Lanah - sort of rape someone can say it, yes - as it skips the whole item template. When writing this, I wanted first to present that what it takes is to access previous elements of the $category... then not sure how I stacked with the silly impression that $category won't pass into the item template, I didn't even give it a thought... At the end both answers suggest the same thing - but mine is dirty/ugly as hell and looks like an amateurish one. So, I upvoted yours and I let mine here at the bottom as an example of blurred thinking coding.